# websocket выдает ошибку ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, websocket

Я новичок и особо не вник в технологию. На localhost websocket работал, а не хостинге не работает.
WebSocket connection to 'ws://e952951e.beget.tech:8000/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

```
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://e952951e.beget.tech:8000');
```

Пишет, что здесь ошибка. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Как у вас поднят серверный сокет? Протоколы совпадают? Адрес e952951e.beget.tech:8000 резолвится?

Comment: 8000 - нет, какой тогда порт?

Comment: Если у вас поднят сокет на 80 порту, то и идти надо на 80, а у вас 8000 указан

Comment: на 80 тоже есть ошибка - Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

Comment: Далее вопросы к провайдеру(может не поддерживаются сокеты или отключены) либо смотреть на проблему с привязкой к коду сервера(на чем написан, какая библиотека, как написан и т.д.)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь